# Using VBOs to render a square

Tags: opengl, vbo, opengl-3

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how VBOs are used. I've been trying to get an image equivalent to:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluPerspective (70, 4.0f / 3, 1, 1000);

glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();

gluLookAt (0, 0, -5,
           0, 0,  0,
           0, 1,  0);

glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f (-1, -1, -1);
glVertex3f (1, -1, -1);
glVertex3f (1, 1, -1);
glVertex3f (-1, -1, -1);
glVertex3f (1, 1, -1);
glVertex3f (-1, 1, -1);
glEnd ();
```

which results in a white square. Using VBOs, from what I could gather from an assortment of tutorials, should change the code to:

```
float vertexes[][3] = {
    { 1,  1, -1},
    { 1, -1, -1},
    {-1,  1, -1},
    {-1, -1, -1},
};

unsigned int indexes[] = {
    3, 1, 0,
    3, 0, 2,
};

GLuint vbo, ibo;

glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glGenBuffers (1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluPerspective (70, 4.0f / 3, 1, 1000);

glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();

gluLookAt (0, 0, -5,
       0, 0,  0,
       0, 1,  0);

glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof vertexes, vertexes, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof indexes, indexes, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawElements (GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

However, this does not render anything.

Comment: "*from what I could gather from an assortment of tutorials*" I've never seen any tutorial endorse that code or anything like it.

Comment: @MeDiCS - I'm just guessing, but I'm not certain if you're allowed to set a pointer to a buffer that hasn't been created yet. No memory is allocated until glBufferData is called, so glVertexPointer wouldn't be able to store a pointer to the memory because it doesn't exist yet. I suggest trying putting glBufferData before glVertexPointer. Also you should use `glGetError` when your code is not working.

Comment: @Tim: OpenGL is accepting every single command --- all calls are wrapped with a macro that checks for errors. Also, moving `glVertexPointer` right after `glBufferData` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what my error was. This call:

```
glDrawElements (GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

asks OpenGL to draw a triangle with two vertexes, and not two triangles with three vertexes each as I thought. The correct call is:

```
glDrawElements (GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

VBO is used to supply data to the OpenGL rendering system but you need to hold the hand and walk him through it....

1. Tell him what are the vertices he needs to plot and the cartesian coordinates of the same.
   You have done that correctly.
2. Next you need to tell him how to do that. This is done by the array indices array. That is also done correctly by you.

But I have a feeling that this is happening because between the consecutive calls to glBindBuffer() you are not clearing the buffers so its having trouble which buffer to put it into.

Please look at this sample (written by me)

```
void InitVBO() 
{
    glGenBuffers(noOfVBO, vboHandle);   // create an interleaved VBO object
    for(int i =0;i<noOfVBO;i++)
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle[i]);   // bind the first handle 
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*masterNumberVertices[i], masterSolidVertex[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW); // allocate space and copy the position data over
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   // clean up 
        glGenBuffers(1, &indexVBO[i]); 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBO[i]); 
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint)*masterNumberIndices[i], masterSolidIndices[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // load the index data 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);  // clean up
    } 
  // by now, we moved the position and color data over to the graphics card. There will be no redundant data copy at drawing time 
}
```

And this is the square drawing routine.

```
//Draw Cube 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle[3]); 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBO[3]); 
  glVertexPointer(4,GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),(char*) NULL+0); 
  glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex),(char*) NULL+16); 
  glColorPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,  sizeof(Vertex),(char*) NULL+32);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  gluPerspective(60, 1, .1, 100); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  gluLookAt(5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1); 
  glRotatef(x_angle, 0, 0,1); 
  glRotatef(y_angle, 0,1,0); 
  glScalef(scale_size, scale_size, scale_size); 
  glTranslatef(0,-1.5,-1.5);
  //glScalef(1,5,5); 
  glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, masterNumberIndices[3], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (char*) NULL+0);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hmm, unbinding and rebinding buffers does not change anything, and I can't see anything in the rendering code I might have missed. The OpenGL initialization may be different?

Comment: No, but I guess SDL does this already. Either way, it does work when I use `glBegin`/`glEnd`...

Comment: SDL to create a window and GL context, and Glew for OpenGL itself.